# How to call a function inside a function node

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I'm trying to increase the cyclomatic complexity of my code . but when i trying to call a function inside a function it weren't call ,

```
function purchaseRequest (purchaseData,vendorId,callback) {
console.log('==============purchaseRequest==============')
testFunction();
}

function testFunction() {
  console.log('==============testFunction==============')

}
```

out put is ==>> **purchaseRequest**

Comment: How are you calling the function purchaseRequest? can you add a little more code to improve the context in which this code above is being used?

Comment: Add some more code regarding which function are you calling purchaseRequest or testFunction?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

It is working fine, explain how are you calling function?

Answer (score 1):

Calling purchaseRequest() prints:
`==============purchaseRequest==============`
`==============testFunction==============`
as expected.